# How do I deserialize a Json object?

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, json-deserialization

This is the code I use to deserialize JSON.But when I try writing it in console, it says "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String, System.Object]"

```
System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
string Jayson = wc.DownloadString("http://api.urbandictionary.com/v0/define?term=api");
object obj = JsonHelper.Deserialize(Jayson);
Dictionary<string, object> values = 
        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(Jayson);
Console.WriteLine(values);
```

How do I deserialize it and extract only the "definition" from the JSON?

Comment: Could you provide sample value of "Jayson"?

Comment: If you open http://api.urbandictionary.com/v0/define?term=api you can see all of the JSON. I want to extract ":[{"definition":

Comment: It's not a problem about trying to write a Dictionary? What about something like  values.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Key));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create some concrete types to map to and deserialize using those rather than more generic types, for example:

```
public class Result
{

    [JsonProperty("definition")]
    public string Definition { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("author")]
    public string Author { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("permalink")]
    public string PermaLink { get; set; }

}

public class Results
{

    [JsonProperty("list")]
    public List<Result> List { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("tags")]
    public List<string> Tags { get; set; }

}
```

Then:

```
var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Results>(json);
```

You can then iterate the definitions:

```
foreach(var result in results.List)
    Console.WriteLine(result.Definition);
```

Json.NET will ignore the other properties it can't map so you can add/remove them as needed.

Comment: When I try the for command it gives me an error. "
Error CS1579 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Results' because 'Results' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator' "

Comment: one more question... There are apparently multiple definitions in the link. How do I get only the first and ignore the rest?

Answer (score 1):

You're getting "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String, System.Object]" because `Console.WriteLine` can only write strings and it doesn't know how to turn a dictionary into a string.

To print all the entries, loop over the collection and print each entry:

```
System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
string Jayson = wc.DownloadString("http://api.urbandictionary.com/v0/define?term=api");
object obj = JsonHelper.Deserialize(Jayson);
Dictionary<string, object> values = 
        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(Jayson);

foreach(var entry in values)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{entry.Key} : {entry.Value}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just parse your json string to a JObject and then get the "defenition" property from it

```
jObj = JObject.Parse("yourJsonString");    
string defenition = jo["definition"];
```